# sql query stops after executing first row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Using navicat and the problem is I would like to create an event, name it, schedule it, and fill the event with instruction for carry out at a later date. I have the code and when I run the query to create the event it will only paste the very first line of instruction set into the event schedule.   example  here is the code......

```
CREATE EVENT `replaceTents` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR COMMENT 'Changes Tents to Map Items' DO

UPDATE `Object_DATA` SET `Classname` = 'Land_Campfire_burning' AND `Inventory` = '[]' WHERE `Classname` = 'TentStorage' AND `Inventory` = '[[[],[]],[["ItemGoldBar2oz"],[2]],[[],[]]]';

UPDATE `Object_DATA` SET `Classname` = 'WarfareBunkerSign' AND `Inventory` = '[]' WHERE `Classname` = 'TentStorage' AND `Inventory` = '[[[],[]],[["ItemGoldBar2oz"],[2]],[[],[]]]';

UPDATE `Object_DATA` SET `Classname` = 'Land_Fire_barrel_burning' AND `Inventory` = '[]' WHERE `Classname` = 'TentStorage' AND `Inventory` = '[[[],[]],[["ItemGoldBar10oz"],[2]],[[],[]]]';

UPDATE `Object_DATA` SET `Classname` = 'HeliHCivil' AND `Inventory` = '[]' WHERE `Classname` = 'TentStorage' AND `Inventory` = '[[[],[]],[["ItemGoldBar10oz"],[5]],[[],[]]]';

UPDATE `Object_DATA` SET `Classname` = 'Land_Ind_TankSmall' AND `Inventory` = '[]' WHERE `Classname` = 'TentStorage' AND `Inventory` = '[[[],[]],[["ItemGoldBar10oz"],[9]],[[],[]]]';

UPDATE `Object_DATA` SET `Classname` = 'Land_Ind_IlluminantTower' AND `Inventory` = '[]' WHERE `Classname` = 'TentStorage' AND `Inventory` = '[[[],[]],[["ItemBriefcase100oz"],[1]],[[],[]]]';

UPDATE `Object_DATA` SET `Classname` = 'WarfareBAirport' AND `Inventory` = '[]' WHERE `Classname` = 'TentStorage' AND `Inventory` = '[[[],[]],[["ItemBriefcase100oz"],[3]],[[],[]]]';
```

So the problem is this is the only one that shows up saved inside the event because its first on the list, How would I carry on with the SQL to print the entire set into a single event schedule?

```
UPDATE `Object_DATA` SET `Classname` = 'Land_Campfire_burning' AND `Inventory` = '[]' WHERE `Classname` = 'TentStorage' AND `Inventory` = '[[[],[]],[["ItemGoldBar2oz"],[2]],[[],[]]]';
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: based on `Inventory` i would your schema is poor

Comment: The game Inventory system is setup like this, this is not something I can change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the `DO BEGIN` ... `END` as shown in the last example of http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

**EDIT 1:** Also, as mentioned at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html:

> As with stored routines, you can use compound-statement syntax in the DO clause by using the BEGIN and END keywords

Comment: I tried to use the BEGIN-END function earlier with no avail, I ended up seperating them into different events with different names but I would really like to still try and figure this out.. thanks for the help.

Comment: Read the documentation again.  Both of the links in this answer give you the piece you are not seeing: `DELIMITER`.  You *need* the `BEGIN`/`END`... but if you don't set your statement delimiter, the first semicolon is treated as the end of the statement. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html